# Dynamic Queue using Linked List // BUS ERROR: 10 (C++)

Tags: c++, debugging, linked-list, queue, bus

Hi I am implementing a basic linked-list based dynamic Queue class and when running the test I get "bus error : 10". I am new with using terminal (MAC OS X) and I would like some help finding what is wrong with my code or maybe the way I am trying to run it. It compiles good.

Links to code:

[HEADER FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0gzydrfaareavwt/queue.h?dl=0)

[CPP FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5ykwx3vizsuly1/queue.cpp?dl=0)

TEST CODE:

```
//
//  Test Program 1 for Dynamic Int Queue Class
//
#include <iostream>   // for I/O facilities
#include "queue.h" //  basic_int_queue declarations
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

   bool OK = true ;
   Queue q1 ;
   if( ! q1.empty() ) OK = false ;
   q1.enqueue(1);
   if( q1.empty() ) OK = false ;
   q1.enqueue(2);
   q1.enqueue(3);
   q1.enqueue(4);
   if( q1.front() != 1 )  OK = false ;
   q1.dequeue();
   q1.dequeue();
   q1.dequeue();
   if( q1.front() != 4 )  OK = false ;
   if( q1.dequeue() != 4 ) OK = false ;
   if( ! q1.empty() ) OK = false ;

   if( OK ){
      cout << "GOOD" << endl ;
      return 0 ;
   }else{
      cout << "BAD" << endl ;
      return -1 ;
   }
}
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: You might consider building your program with the compiler option `-g` to generate debug information and then run your application through a debugger like `gdb`. It should tell you where your bus error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `queue.cpp` file `enqueue` implementation, you need to allocate a new node on the heap using `new`. For example, changing the following lines in your `enqueue`

```
node * temp;
temp->next = NULL;
temp->data = item;
```

to

```
node * temp = new node(item, NULL);
```

will get rid of the bus error.

Also, at the end of your `dequeue` implementation, you need to

`delete temp;`

before

`return item;`

Otherwise the `delete temp;` line is unreachable, and you'd have memory leaks.

One last thing, normally you should

`#include "queue.h"`

in your `queuen.cpp`. Not the other way around.

Comment: Your help was useful but now I am getting this:

>>Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


What does it mean??

Comment: Looks like you were trying to compile an executable using just the `queue.cpp`. You need to also have the test cpp file (the file containing the code you pasted in your original post) in your compile command. So something like `g++ queue.cpp test.cpp`.